# INSERT and set a field to copy the newly inserted id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to INSERT a row, and simultaneously set one of the fields to contain the inserted row's ID? (the "self" id)

I'm trying to avoid using multiple queries if possible (it would be 3 queries in total otherwhise)

Something like this (but probably not):

```
INSERT INTO thetable (email, phone, activationkey) VALUES ($email, $phone, CONCAT(THIS_NEW_ID, md5($activation) )
```

Comment: How are you using PDO when you're explicitly putting the variables in the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @Kermit This is just a simple example. I use prepared statements etc. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to store duplicated data?

You could change your table structure and just run:

```
INSERT INTO thetable (email, phone, activation_suffix) 
     VALUES ($email, $phone, md5($activation))
```

And then you have all the data you need.

You can always concat when you query the table:

```
SELECT CONCAT(id, activation_suffix) activationkey
  FROM thetable
 WHERE ...
```

**UPDATE**

On second thoughts, do you really need the id as part of the activationkey?

I wouldn't want to give any user the id for their record in my table unless it is hashed/encrypted.

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I just need to use lastinsertid() too then when sending out activationkey to user. "Here is the key: lastinsertid() . md5($activation)". Thats ok. Thanks

Comment: Well I need SOMETHING that can be clearly identified to that user's row, to use along the md5() ("salt"?)

Comment: @mowgli I can see two things in the table already.. `email` and `activationkey`! :)

Comment: Ok, I have a lot of fields.. but the ID will never change, so I thought I would use that to be safe. But I cant imagine where it would be bad to join the id with the hash..? Nobody can use the id to anything anywhere on the site, not even with URL's (except at the activation.. but then its joined and messed with the hash)

Comment: I figured it's good to use a separate "salt" instead of just md5().. and $activation already comes from md5($theemailaddress). Sry if its messy explained..

Comment: Actually I dont see why its not advisable to output the ID, when it's fine to output the emailaddress. Both can potentially (in worst case) be used to identify/manipulate the db ?

Comment: @mowgli It's not messed up with the hash if you just concat it onto the beginning.. I'd probably hash the email, phone and the date the user got added.. maybe with a constant as well. I'd keep the id separate.

Comment: Yeah I just thought about using the user-date too (perhaps converted to only-numbers).. maybe thats the best way

Comment: @mowgli The email_address is something you have to reveal to the user.. id isn't. It is best to minimise the points of entry into your site.

Comment: Ok, so I insert the date, email, and a simple md5(). Then I use lastinsertid() to select the newly created date, join it with the md5, and send that activation link to the user. That should be safe enough for me :)

Comment: On second thought.. why not just combine the **current date** with md5(some.user.value).. No need to retrieve the specific user date. Safe enough for this

Comment: @mowgli sounds like you have it sorted now. :)